# Javascript object relationhips

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to better understand object relationships in Javascript. I have the following object:

```
var product = {id: 1, name: 'Test Product', sku: {id: 2, sku: 'ABC'}};
```

Now, I also set the following variable:

```
var appSku = product.sku;
```

If product.sku changes to a new object, will appSku update? Meaning, if somewhere else in the code I do this:

```
product.sku = {id: 3, sku: 'EFG'};
```

How can I ensure that the `appSku` variable gets the new value of `product.sku`?

Comment: Yes I tried it out in js console and know it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If `product.sku` changes to a new object, will `appSku` update?

No

> How can I ensure that the `appSku` variable gets the new value of `product.sku`?

You would have to write it as a function accesses *sku* via a reference to the *Object* `product`, e.g.

```
var appSku = (function (o) {
    return function () {
        return o.sku;
    }
}(product));
```

And always use `appSku()`

This isn't really helpful in your case, though as using `product.sku` directly is much cleaner

---

This said, if `product.sku` is not changed to a *new Object*, but rather the previous one just has it's properties modified then `appSku` and `product.sku` would still be the same thing

Comment: Does it need to be written as you show it with a closer around it? What is the reason for that? Can't it just be a single function that returns the value of product.sku?